# IntelliJ IDEA runs full test suite when I try to debug a single unit test

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've inherited a Maven project that includes a large number of unit tests and integration tests. I added a unit test for a change I've made. However, this unit test is failing and so are a number of integration tests (because they rely on a specific environment). I want to debug my unit test (and the method under test), but when I right-click on the test method and choose "debug", IntelliJ IDEA does a "Build" first, and that's the Maven build which tries to execute all tests and integration tests. As a result, the build fails and I can't therefore debug my unit test. How can I get around this?

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis yes, that solved it, thank you. However, now when I change the test it doesn't recompile it when I re-run it.

Comment: The "before launch" action was just plain "Build". But I think that IntelliJ's plain "Build" command delegates to mvn build.

Comment: I couldn't find how to replace it with a custom mvn command, but when I looked around the IDE settings I found a checkbox "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven", and unticked it. It now works well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij has specific configuration for the builds. 
The default configuration is the "build" command which will build the project.

You can change this command into a maven command so you will manually skip the tests

to do that click edit configuration and go to the profile configuration you want to change. :

- At the very bottom you can see the before launch part :

  [image: default config]
- from there you remove the previous with the ( - ) and you click the ( + ) to add a new one. Scroll down in the list to find the `maven goal`

  [image: maven goal]
- once you check it you have to add the manual command there. Note: You dont need to write mvn as its ommited.

  [image: maven command]

An other approach you can follow is to instruct intellij to use maven for all of its actions by delegating everything to maven. 
to do that just go to the settings and follow the path :

Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools > Maven > Runner

and check the Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven.

[image]